# PHP script or class to create SVG images/xml

Tags: javascript, php, svg

I have to write a php script that will generate and return them to the browser. For example a user will enter the url: generator.com/rectangle.svg?w=5h=10 or generator.com/linegraph.svg?linecolor=blue&linewidth=2&data=12:21,123:323,232,1232 and the server will return a .svg image. The images will usually be basic geometric shapes.

Does any one know of a good php script that can be used to generate SVG graphics?

I have found these so far:
svgdreams.com/index.php
https://github.com/TimOliver/PHP-Framework-Classes/blob/master/svg.class.php
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7073-PHP-Create-and-edit-vectorial-graphics-in-SVG-files.html

Also is there anyway of adding animations to an SVG file? I doubt you can embed a javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider doing all SVG job in the client side (initial image and animation), using a library that seem appropriate? (I'd had a look at https://svgdotjs.github.io/ if I had to do the job)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the library I am also looking for good popular client-side libraries. For the project however I want the user to add the images on other pages use the src attribute i.e: <img src="" /> or embed them in pages by calling functions and supplying the appropriete variables.